# How to implement express-ws route

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, websocket

UPDATE:

I needed to set up express-ws properly:

```
const express = require('express');
let expressWs = require('express-ws');
expressWs = expressWs(express());
const app = expressWs.app;
const router = express.Router();

const createError = require('http-errors');
const path = require('path');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const logger = require('morgan');
...
const playerHeadingRouter = require('./routes/playerHeading')(router, db);
```

along with my route module:

```
module.exports = (router, db) => {
  router.get('/api/player/:id', (req, res, next) => {
    res.end();
  });

  router.ws('/api/player/:id', (ws, req) => {
    ws.on('message', function(msg) {
      const coords = JSON.parse(msg);
      db.any(`UPDATE "user" SET x = ${coords.x} WHERE id = ${req.params.id}`)
      db.any(`UPDATE "user" SET y = ${coords.y} WHERE id = ${req.params.id}`)
      db.any(`UPDATE "user" SET geom = ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(x, y),27700) WHERE id = ${req.params.id}`)
        .then(() => {
          // success;
          console.log('msg', msg);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          // error;
          console.log('error', error);
        });
    });
    // socket
  });
}
```

now, when I use chrome websockets client, I can establish a connection to:

```
ws://localhost:3001/api/player-heading/2
```

and send a msg that gets used in a DB query from my express server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're hosting a websocket endpoint, you won't be able to access it over HTTP. You'll need to connect to the ws:// endpoint with a websocket client. You can use a Chrome extension [like this one](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/simple-websocket-client/pfdhoblngboilpfeibdedpjgfnlcodoo?hl=en) to do so.

Comment: Thanks.

Trying to open ws://localhost:3001/echo gives me "undefined".

Comment: Your second code snippet is set to echo whatever the client sends. If you send a message from the client is it returned?

Comment: Please see the update. I can establish a connection now, and I am able to send data to the express server via the browser plugin that you mentioned. Thanks again.

Comment: The express-ws library no longer seems to be actively maintained. If you want similar functionality, I've posted my solution this his problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69773285/defining-websocket-routes-for-express/69773286#69773286